# How can I ignore unchanged forms of my formset when saving?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, formset

I have a `FormSet` of `ModelForm` and I need to ignore forms that are not filled when submitting my form.

Here is the `ModelForm`:

```
class associe(forms.ModelForm):
#Associé 
date_naissance = forms.DateField(initial=datetime.date.today,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=
                            {
                                'type':'date'
                            }),required = False)
associe_gerant = forms.CharField(initial="0",label='',widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=ASSOCIE_GERANT,attrs={'oninput':'this.className = ""'}),required = False)
tassocie = forms.ChoiceField(initial="Physique",choices = TYPE_ASSOCIE,widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange':'TypeAssocie(this)'}),required = False)
nassocie = forms.ChoiceField(initial="Marocain",choices = NATIONALITE,widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange':'NationaliteAssocie(this)'}),required = False)
tapport = forms.CharField(initial="0",label="type d'apport",widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=APPORT,attrs={'onchange':'TypeApport(this)'}),required = False)
montant_apport = forms.FloatField(initial="0",required = False)
type_apport = forms.CharField(initial="0",max_length=100,required = False)
valeur_estimatif = forms.FloatField(initial="0",required = False) 
date_naissance_etrange = forms.DateField(initial=datetime.date.today,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=
                            {
                                'type':'date'
                            }),required = False)
date_naissance_gerant_asso = forms.DateField(initial=datetime.date.today,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=
                            {
                                'type':'date'
                            }),required = False)
class Meta:
    model = PerP
    fields = ('nom','prenom','civilite','nassocie','tassocie','cin','date_naissance','lieu_naissance','adresse','passeport','num_sejour','date_delivrance','lien_delivrance','denomination','siege','forme_juridique','capital','ville','num_rc','civilite_gerant_asso','representant_legal','date_naissance_gerant_asso','pass_cin','nationalite_gerant_asso','adresse_gerant_asso','nom_etrange','prenom_etrange','nationalite','date_naissance_etrange','adresse_etrange',)
```

My `FormSet`:

```
FormSet=formset_factory(associe,extra=7)
```

In my **views.py** this is the method that submits the form:

```
def saveToBase(request):
    associe=FormSet(request.POST)
    if associe.is_valid():
        for a in associe:
            if a.is_valid() and  a.has_changed():
                a.save()
    return render(request,'societe/accueil.html')
```

but I'm always getting `has_changed == True` when I print the value of `a.has_changed()`.

After hours of searching, I know now that I should add `initial` to my form, but I can't figure out how can I do so, especially when I'm working with a FormSet and not a normal form.